# Convolution of a distribution with a $C^{N}$ function.

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

I've been working on the following Problem from Friedlander's introduction to the theory of distributions:

> Show that if $u$ is a distribution of order $N$ and with compact support on
>   $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and if $\psi \in C^{N}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, then $u* \psi$
>   is of the form $u* \psi = \langle  u(y), \psi(x-y) \rangle$ and that
>   $u* \psi$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

- Approach one:

I have tried to use the fact that $C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is dense in the space of distributions. To do so, I chose $\{u_{k}\} \subset C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$  such that $\text{supp}(u_{k}) \subset \text{supp}(u) + B(0,1)$  and $u_{k} \to u$ in the the space of distributions. Then, I can define $g_{k}(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} u_{k}(y) \psi(x-y) d y = u_{k} * \psi(x)$. I want to say that $\{g_{k}\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is uniformly equicontinuous, and therefore by Arzela-Ascoli, a subsequence converges locally uniformly and is consequently  continuous. Unfortunately, if $u = \delta_{0}$, then my functions $u_{k}$ are not locally bounded so I have no hope of applying Arzela-Ascoli.

- Approach two:

Use a standard mollifiers argument, and define
$\langle u* \psi, \phi \rangle = \langle u(x), \langle \psi(y), \phi(x+y) \rangle \rangle \quad \forall \phi \in C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^{n}).$

We note that $\langle \psi(y), \phi(x+y) \rangle \in C^{\infty}$, so this is well-defined. We can then use mollifiers $\varphi_{\epsilon}^{x}$ supported in a ball of radius $\epsilon$ about $x$ that integrate to $1$ and approximate the $\delta$ function as $\epsilon \to 0$, and define
$$
g(x) = \langle u*  \psi, \varphi_{\epsilon}^{x} \rangle.
$$

Again, I don't know how to show that this $g$ is continuous, since using the fact that $u$ is of finite order, I can get a bound on $|g(x) - g(y)|$, but it depends on the supremum over the support of $u$ all derivatives of $\psi$ of order less than or equal to $N$ multiplied by $\varphi_{\epsilon}^{x}$, which grows like $\epsilon^{-n}$ as $\epsilon \to 0$, and hence is a problem.

---

I'm open to any ideas  of how to conclude using either of my approaches as well as any new methods.

Cheers.

Comment: a distribution of order $N$ should mean that it is the $N$th derivative of a continuous function, hence you are supposed to integrate by part $N$ times, or to write that $f' \ast h = (f \ast h)'$  (because the derivative operator can be written as the convolution by $\delta'$)

Comment: @user: At least with the definition of "order N" what you are writing is not true. Order N means (essentially) that the value of $u (\psi) $ only depends on the first N($\pm 1$) derivatives of $\psi $. This does not imply that $u $ is the Nth derivative of a continuous function, e.g. $1_{(0,\infty)} $ is of order 0 (or 1, depending on how you count).

Comment: @PhoemueX : $\delta(x)$ is the derivative of $sign(x)$ which is the derivative of $|x|$, hence in my definition $\delta$ is of order $2$, maybe the definition assumes it is of order $1$, and your definition is equivalent

Comment: This is the standard definition: A distribution $u\in\mathscr D'(\Omega)$ has order $\le n$ if, for every compact set $K\subseteq \Omega$, there is a constant $c\ge 0$ such that $|u(\varphi)|\le c \sup\lbrace |\partial^\alpha \varphi(x)|: x\in\Omega, |\alpha|\le n\rbrace$ for all smooth $\varphi$ with support in $K$.